# Как подключиться к postgres при использовании uvicorn.run

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi, uvicorn, asyncpg

У меня телеграм бот (**main.py**), работающий на **python3** и **asyncpg**.
А так же программа (**webhook.py**) **fastapi** **uvicorn.run**, которая принимает платежи. После этого она выдаёт вип пользователю и записывает данные в БД.

Но у неё проблемы с подключением БД. Хотя тот же файл подключения как и у бота.
Условный код **webhook.py**:

```
from src.base import db

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/')
async def webhook(request: Request):
    await db.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=443)
```

Мне нужно воспользоваться и БД, и функциями в боте, которые так же импортируются, но БД выдаёт ошибку:

> asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError: cannot perform operation:
> another operation is in progress

или

> RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-55'
> coro=<_create_ssl_connection() running at
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py:684>
> cb=[_release_waiter(<Future pendi...ask_wakeup()]>)() at
> /usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:387]> got Future <Future pending
> cb=[_chain_future.._call_check_cancel() at
> /usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/futures.py:385]> attached to a different
> loop

Это происходит независимо от того включён ли основной бот или нет. Как это можно исправить? Ибо всё уже перечитал.

Comment: это смотрели? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73613457/runtimeerror-task-running-at-at-got-future-future-pending-cb-protocol

Answer (score 1):

Была ошибка в реализации моего подключения:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
  self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  self.loop.run_until_complete(self.init(**kwargs))

async def init(self, **kwargs):
  self.pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(**kwargs)
```

Из-за loop. Сделал init при использования любого метода в первый раз и всё заработало.